# Field nameSpan has no corresponding field in template file Login.ui.xml

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Eclipse 3.7 GWT 2.4
When I create templated UiBinder class with xml
I see issue on
@UiField
SpanElement nameSpan;

"Field nameSpan has no corresponding field in template file Login.ui.xml"

How fix it?

Login.java

```
public class Login extends UIObject {

    private static LoginUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoginUiBinder.class);

    interface LoginUiBinder extends UiBinder<Element, Login> {
    }

    @UiField
    SpanElement nameSpan; 

    public Login(String firstName) {
        setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        nameSpan.setInnerText(firstName);
    }
```

}

Login.ui.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'>
    <div>
        Hello,
        <span ui:field='nameSpan' />
    </div>
</ui:UiBin
```

Comment: just do project->clean and issue has gone

Answer (score 1):

> *"Field nameSpan has no corresponding field in template file Login.ui.xml"*

It states that there is no corresponding type of field in login.ui.xml as define by @UiField in login.java

Your login.ui.xml should be something like :

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder' xmlns:s='urn:import:com.google.gwt.dom.client'>
<div>
    Hello,
    <s:SpanElement ui:field='nameSpan' />
</div>
```